# Ajax пагинация Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ajax

На сайте Wordpress есть ajax пагинация и ajax фильтр. Всё работает корректно по отдельности. Но, когда применяем фильтр и переходим по ссылке пагинации, переходит на нефильтрованную вторую страницу. Если на второй странице применить фильтр, то отображаются данные уже второй фильтрованной страницы (не с начала, а именно вторая страница фильтрации). То есть, образно говоря, пагинация не запоминает данные фильтра. Как их передать?

functions.php

```
// Приём и обработка запроса

add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxpagination', 'ajax_pagination_in_filter');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxpagination', 'ajax_pagination_in_filter');
function ajax_pagination_in_filter()
{

    $link = !empty($_POST['link']) ? esc_attr($_POST['link']) : false;
    $paged = $link ? wp_basename($link) : false;

    query_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'villas',
        'paged' => $paged,

        'orderby' => 'date', // сортировка по дате у нас будет в любом случае (но вы можете изменить/доработать это)
        'order' => $_POST['date'] // ASC или DESC

    ));

    if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()): the_post();
            // adapted for Twenty Seventeen theme
            ?>
            <div class="villas-item">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link-page"></a>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="villas-item__image">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </a>
                <div class="villas-item__info">
                    <div class="villas-item__info_col">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title() ?></h4></a>
                        <a href="#" class="villas-item__address">61JI. Legian, Kuta, Indonesia</a>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        <span class="villas-item__see-m">100 m to the sea</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="villas-item__info_col rating-price">
                        <div class="rating-group">
                            <span class="rating-group_count-villa">9.2</span>
                            <div class="rating-group_reviews">
                                <div class="star-block">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/icons/star-full.svg"
                                         alt="">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/icons/star-full.svg"
                                         alt="">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/icons/star-full.svg"
                                         alt="">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/icons/star-empty.svg"
                                         alt="">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/icons/star-empty.svg"
                                         alt="">
                                </div>
                                <span class="rating-group_reviews-count">
                                    57 reviews
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="villas-item__price">
                            <span class="villas-item__price-count">95</span><span>$</span>
                        </div>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="choose-room-btn">Choose a room</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <a class="like-btn" href="#"><img
                            src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/icons/blue-heart.svg"
                            alt=""></a>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
    else:
        echo '<p>Nothing found for your criteria.</p>';
    endif; ?>

    <div class="pagination-block">
    <!--                        <div class="pagination-left">-->
    <!--                            <p>Show</p>-->
    <!--                            <span>12</span>-->
    <!--                            <a href="#">24</a>-->
    <!--                            <a href="#">36</a>-->
    <!--                        </div>-->
    <div class="pagination-right">
        <?php $args = array(
            'show_all' => false, // показаны все страницы участвующие в пагинации
            'end_size' => 1,     // количество страниц на концах
            'mid_size' => 1,     // количество страниц вокруг текущей
            'prev_next' => true,  // выводить ли боковые ссылки "предыдущая/следующая страница".
            'prev_text' => '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/icons/pagin-arr-left.svg" alt="">',
            'next_text' => '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/icons/pagin-arr-right.svg" alt="">',
            'add_args' => false, // Массив аргументов (переменных запроса), которые нужно добавить к ссылкам.
            'add_fragment' => '',     // Текст который добавиться ко всем ссылкам.

        );

        $pagination = get_the_posts_pagination($args);

        echo str_replace('wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 'villas', $pagination); ?>

    </div>
    </div>


    <?php wp_die();
}


// Создание кастомных переменных
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets');
function my_assets()
{
    global $wp_query;

    wp_register_script('my_assets', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/filter.js', array('jquery'), '', true);

    wp_localize_script('my_assets', 'ajax_pagination', array(
        'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // WordPress AJAX
        'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), // everything about your loop is here

    ));
    wp_enqueue_script('my_assets');
}


add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'true_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'true_filter_function');

function true_filter_function(){

    $link = !empty($_POST['link']) ? esc_attr($_POST['link']) : false;
    $paged = $link ? wp_basename($link) : false;


    query_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'villas',
        'paged' => $paged,

        'orderby' => 'date', // сортировка по дате у нас будет в любом случае (но вы можете изменить/доработать это)
        'order' => $_POST['date'] // ASC или DESC
    ));
//
//    $args = array(
//        'orderby' => 'date', // сортировка по дате у нас будет в любом случае (но вы можете изменить/доработать это)
//        'order'   => $_POST['date'] // ASC или DESC
//    );

    // для таксономий
//    if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] )
//
//    $args['tax_query'] = array(
//        array(
//            'taxonomy' => 'category',
//            'field' => 'id',
//            'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
//        )
//    );

    // создаём массив $args['meta_query'] если указана хотя бы одна цена или отмечен чекбокс
    if( isset( $_POST['cena_min'] ) || isset( $_POST['cena_max'] ) || ( isset( $_POST['featured_image'] ) && $_POST['featured_image'] == 'on' ) )
        $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'AND' ); // AND значит все условия meta_query должны выполняться

    // условие 1: цена больше $_POST['cena_min']
    if( isset( $_POST['cena_min'] ) )
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'cena',
            'value' => $_POST['cena_min'],
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>'
        );

    // условие 2: цена меньше $_POST['cena_max']
    if( isset( $_POST['cena_max'] ) )
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'cena',
            'value' => $_POST['cena_max'],
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<'
        );

    // условие 3: миниатюра имеется
    if( isset( $_POST['featured_image'] ) && $_POST['featured_image'] == 'on' )
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        );

    global $wp_query;

    if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()): the_post();
            // adapted for Twenty Seventeen theme
            ?>
            <div class="villas-item">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link-page"></a>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="villas-item__image">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </a>
                <div class="villas-item__info">
                    <div class="villas-item__info_col">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title() ?></h4></a>
                        <a href="#" class="villas-item__address">61JI. Legian, Kuta, Indonesia</a>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        <span class="villas-item__see-m">100 m to the sea</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="villas-item__info_col rating-price">
                        <div class="rating-group">
                            <span class="rating-group_count-villa">9.2</span>
                            <div class="rating-group_reviews">
                                <div class="star-block">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/icons/star-full.svg"
                                         alt="">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/icons/star-full.svg"
                                         alt="">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/icons/star-full.svg"
                                         alt="">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/icons/star-empty.svg"
                                         alt="">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/icons/star-empty.svg"
                                         alt="">
                                </div>
                                <span class="rating-group_reviews-count">
                                    57 reviews
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="villas-item__price">
                            <span class="villas-item__price-count">95</span><span>$</span>
                        </div>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="choose-room-btn">Choose a room</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <a class="like-btn" href="#"><img
                        src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/icons/blue-heart.svg"
                        alt=""></a>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
    else:
        echo '<p>Nothing found for your criteria.</p>';
    endif; ?>



    <div class="pagination-block">
    <!--                        <div class="pagination-left">-->
    <!--                            <p>Show</p>-->
    <!--                            <span>12</span>-->
    <!--                            <a href="#">24</a>-->
    <!--                            <a href="#">36</a>-->
    <!--                        </div>-->
    <div class="pagination-right">
        <?php $args = array(
            'show_all' => false, // показаны все страницы участвующие в пагинации
            'end_size' => 1,     // количество страниц на концах
            'mid_size' => 1,     // количество страниц вокруг текущей
            'prev_next' => true,  // выводить ли боковые ссылки "предыдущая/следующая страница".
            'prev_text' => '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/icons/pagin-arr-left.svg" alt="">',
            'next_text' => '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/icons/pagin-arr-right.svg" alt="">',
            'add_args' => false, // Массив аргументов (переменных запроса), которые нужно добавить к ссылкам.
            'add_fragment' => '',     // Текст который добавиться ко всем ссылкам.

        );

        $pagination = get_the_posts_pagination($args);

        echo str_replace('wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 'villas', $pagination); ?>

    </div>
    </div>


    <?php wp_die();


}
```

file.js

```
    // Контейнер с контентом
    let mainBox = $('#response');

    // Отправка ajax запроса при клике по ссылке пагинации
    mainBox.on( 'click', '.pagination .nav-links a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let linkPage = $(this).attr('href');
        let titlePage = $(this).text();

        history.pushState({page_title: titlePage},'', linkPage);

        ajaxPage(linkPage);

    });

    // Отслеживание события нажатия кнопок браузера Вперед/Назад
    window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e){
        document.title = e.state.page_title;
        ajaxPage(location.href);
    }, false);

    // Ajax функция
    function ajaxPage(linkPage) {

        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_pagination.ajaxurl,
            data : {
                'action': 'myfilter',
                'link': linkPage,
                'posts': ajax_pagination.posts,
            },
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( response ) {
                mainBox.animate({opacity: 0.7}, 300);
            },
            success : function( posts ){
                if( posts ) {

                    mainBox.html( posts ); // insert new posts

                }

                mainBox.animate({opacity: 1}, 300);

            }

        });

    }




    $('#filter').submit(function(){
        let linkP = location.href;
        let filter = $(this);
        let dataArray = filter.serializeArray();
        dataArray.push({
            name: "link", value: linkP,
        });
        $.ajax({
            url:ajax_pagination.ajaxurl, // обработчик
            data:dataArray, // данные
            type:filter.attr('method'), // тип запроса
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').text('Загружаю...'); // изменяем текст кнопки
            },
            success:function(posts){

                // ajax_pagination.posts = data.posts;

                mainBox.html(posts);
                console.log(dataArray);

                filter.find('button').text('Применить фильтр'); // возвращаеи текст кнопки
                //
                // mainBox.html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });




});
```

Answer (score 3):

Решил задачу. Нужно было передать данные из формы в запрос пагинации. Сделал это таким образом:

````
        let dataArray = $('#filter').serializeArray();
        dataArray.push({
            name: "link", value: linkPage,
            // name: "posts", value: ajax_pagination.posts,
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_pagination.ajaxurl,
            data : dataArray,
            // dataType : 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                mainBox.animate({opacity: 0.7}, 300);
            },
            success : function( posts ){
                if( posts ) {

                    mainBox.html( posts ); // insert new posts
                    console.log(dataArray);
                }

                mainBox.animate({opacity: 1}, 300);

            }

        });

    }```
````